# How to use another content page view in listview datatemplate of xmarin form xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Hi I am trying to use nesting of view with corresponding view model. I have guideView.xaml I want to display it under another page CampsiteViewPage Listview control's datatemplate. Also I want apply viewmodel guideViewModel to it in listView
My guideView code as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
           xmlns:b="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Behaviors;assembly=Xamarin.Behaviors"
         x:Class="InspectionApp.Views.GuideView"
 x:Name="GuideViewPage">  
 <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" MinimumHeightRequest="50" Padding="10,0,10,0">
<Label Text="{Binding GuideName}" VerticalOptions="Center"  WidthRequest="100" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
<ListView  RowHeight="100" HorizontalOptions="End" ItemsSource="{Binding GuidePrices, Mode=TwoWay}" >
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ViewCell>
        <ViewCell.View>
          <StackLayout  Orientation="Horizontal">
            <controls:BindablePicker ItemsSource="{Binding Prices}" WidthRequest="150" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProduct, Mode=TwoWay}" />
</StackLayout>
        </ViewCell.View>
      </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

And main page where I want above view get rendered along with its viewmodel

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:i18n="clr-namespace:InspectionApp.MarkupExtensions;assembly=InspectionApp"
         xmlns:cview="clr-namespace:InspectionApp.Views;assembly=InspectionApp"
         x:Class="InspectionApp.Views.CampsiteView"
         Title="{Binding Name, StringFormat='Order form: {0}'}"
         x:Name="CampsiteViewPage">
  <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" >
<Label Text=" Guides" Font="30"/>
<ListView  RowHeight="100"  ItemsSource="{Binding GuideView}">
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
    <ViewCell>
<!-- Here I want guideView content get loded along with command and properties -->
      <cview:GuideView></cview:GuideView>
   </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

I need your help to achieve this or is there another proper way to implement same please reply here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

you can create `GuideView` as a `View` instead of a `Page`.

**GuideView:**

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:b="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Behaviors;assembly=Xamarin.Behaviors"
             x:Class="InspectionApp.Views.GuideView"
             x:Name="GuideView">
  <ContentView.Content>
      <!--Your guide design goes here-->
  </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

**GuidePage:**

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:b="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Behaviors;assembly=Xamarin.Behaviors"
             xmlns:cview="clr-namespace:InspectionApp.Views;assembly=InspectionApp.Views"
             x:Class="InspectionApp.Views.GuideView"
             x:Name="GuidePage">
  <ContentPage.Content>
    <cview:GuideView />
  </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

**MainPage:**

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
        xmlns:i18n="clr-namespace:InspectionApp.MarkupExtensions;assembly=InspectionApp"
        xmlns:cview="clr-namespace:InspectionApp.Views;assembly=InspectionApp"
        x:Class="InspectionApp.Views.CampsiteView"
        Title="{Binding Name, StringFormat='Order form: {0}'}"
        x:Name="CampsiteViewPage">
  <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" >
    <Label Text=" Guides" Font="30"/>
    <ListView  RowHeight="100"  ItemsSource="{Binding GuideView}">
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <ViewCell>
             <cview:GuideView/>
          </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
    .
    .
    .
```

Comment: How to access element from contentview.